# Google analytics pagepath duplicate. Url with and without hostname are tracked differently(see image)

Tags: google-analytics

**/** and **/https://www.example.com/** are tracked differently and 
**/categories** , **/https://www.example.com/categories** , **/https://www.example.com/categories/** are tracked differently.
Why is this happening? Is there something wrong with my GA code? if not how can i merge them?

[image: page path duplicate]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its about Set up of Google Analytics application and is not programing related might be better suited for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you tell Google that one person was on sitex.com/page1 and another was on /page1, it will decide that those are seperate pages with one user each. This is totally normal behavior for Google Analytics, as it's only frame of reference for a page is the string that it's given: two different strings are two different pages. The problem here is your implementation.

The field you see there is 'Page', which isn't supposed to include the Hostname of the site. That Hostname is being appended by accident, and you should look into your implementation to find out why.